# Old style C function declaration

Tags: c, function, coding-style, runtime

Here's a simple function delcared and defined using old style syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void
error(message,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7)
        char *message;
        char *a1,*a2,*a3,*a4,*a5,*a6,*a7;
{
  fprintf(stderr,message,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7);
}
int main ()
{
  error("[ERROR %d]: %s.\n",110,"Connection timed out");
  return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled and runs correctly to print:

> [ERROR 110]: Connection timed out.

I read that this style doesn't have associated prototype, but how can it convert int to char * automatically at runtime and even the provided arguments are fewer than it's declared?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically, it works because it's too dumb to know better.  Old fashioned K&R C basically doesn't check anything.  You get away with this because,

1. it happens that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char *)` on the particular architecture and compiler combination you're using.  It's not really converting anything, it just figures 32 bits is 32 bits.
2. When you put all those arguments on the stack, it just pushed them in.  When printf uses them, it just uses the ones if needs and leaves the rest alone; they then disappear when the call returns, and no one's the wiser.  However, should you ever happen to try printing seven values where you only passed six arguments, it'll blow up at run time, sometime in creative and unexpected ways.

Comment: for point 1, even i change it to error("[ERROR %d %c]: %s.\n",110,'k', "Connection timed out"); it works. sizeof(int) != sizeof(char) in my machine.

Comment: @Ox, but `char` becomes `int` in function parameters, because of the default argument promotions (§6.5.2.2/6), which include the integer promotions (§6.3.1.1/2).

Comment: Ox, you're not reading closely -- I'm saying sizeof(int) == sizeof(CHAR STAR), ie, size of a pointer to char.  Matthew, you're right about promotions, but note that the arguments are pointer-to-char, not char.

Comment: It has nothing to do with sizes, this still works even if `sizeof(int)!=sizeof(char *)`

Comment: Nonsense.  Try it.  Since you don't have control over the architecture, try, say, passing a double for a float.  If the sizes don't match, the stack unwinds wrong and Bad Things Happen.

Answer (score 12):

Passing too few arguments, or the wrong type (you've done both), causes undefined behavior.  This is exactly why you should never use old style syntax in new code.  If you used new syntax, you would get a "free" prototype from the function definition.  In other words:

```
void
error(char * message,
char * a1, char * a2, char * a3, char * a4, char * a5, char * a6, char * a7)
{

}
```

is also a prototype.

Using old syntax, you have to provide your own, which you haven't.  That means the compiler can't check the calls.

In practice (on your machine), `error` is reading the `int` from the stack into a `char *`.  Then, it passes the `char *` to `fprintf`.  But a `%d` specifier is used, so `fprintf` pops it as an `int`.  This is *more* undefined behavior.  But it happens to work on your machine; `char *` and `int` are likely the same size.

`error` also reads 5 garbage `char *` values off the stack.  It then passes these to `fprintf`, which it ignores because there are only two conversion specifiers.

Comment: i see. i run into this snippet while reading core-utility. it uses this for machines that use old c dialects which doesn't support variadic functions.

Comment: @Ox, [`stdarg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) was standardized 21 years ago.  It's rare to *have* to use a compiler that still doesn't support C89.

Comment: @Mathew, True, but not all code is new. It isn't all that rare to find venerable code with a long heritage that still supplies mechanisms to allow its use on old compilers.

Comment: @RBerteig, that's why I said "in new code."  `core-utility` may have needed it at one point.  But new code probably shouldn't be copying this snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the compiler effectively does have a prototype in scope if it encounters the definition of the function `error()` before encountering its use (this is why old C programmers often order function definitions in files according to their order of use). Consequently, the `110` can get converted to `(char*)110` (not that it would matter on a machine where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char*)`). It would be interesting to see what would happen on a machine where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: Got an x86_64 machine around? You have a machine where `sizeof(int)!=sizeof(char *)` and yes the code should still work.

Comment: The declaration of `error` in this code is not a prototype. There's no such thing as "effectively having a prototype" - either it does or it doesn't, and in this case it doesn't.  The `110` does not get converted. You seem to be assuming all function declarations are prototypes ; but this is an example of one that isn't.

Comment: The fact that old style functions are not prototypes are a reason not to use them. Without prototype there will be no checks of the arguments passed to the function - the compiler will assume that the function takes whatever arguments the code passes to the function. That's also why this actually passes compilation since the function call makes the compiler assume that the function expects three arguments, one `char*`, one `int`  and one `char*` - it's just up to your imagination to figure out how wrong this can get.

Answer (score -2):

Actually there is a conversion of 110 to int, this conversion is done by fprintf, when fprint reads "%d", it tries to convert the corresponding parameter to int. Another point is that the function expect pointers, i.e, memory address, and pointers are integers. If a string had been passed instead of 110, there would still be a number printed, the address of the string at run-time.

Comment: The printf family do not do any type conversions. You have to give the correct specifier.

Comment: The `printf` and similar functions does not do conversion in that way at all. The arguments are passed as the type they are.