# Calling functions by reference with unknown amount of parameters

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

To call a function by just a name, I've came up with this piece of code. This currently works, but I'm not sure if it is undefined behavior. Could anyone shed some light on this and maybe help me come up with a better solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*FunctionCallback)();
void first(char *str);
void second(int , int);
FunctionCallback function[] = {&first, &second};

void first(char *str )
{
    printf( "First: %s\n", str );
}

void second(int x, int y)
{
    int answer;
    answer = x +y;
    printf("Second: %d\n", answer);
}

int main()
{
    function[0]("Working");
    function[1](6, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To see the contrast, try to compile with this: `typedef void (*FunctionCallback)(void);` , all hell breaks loose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be ok, if you are careful. I think UB might be only in case of `first`, which expects `char*`, but is has `const char*` passed to it. Perhaps on some platform, the compiler puts the `const char*` stuff into some weirds place, and writable memory is addressed differently. But that is exotic, hypothetic.

Anyways, to be clear, in C:

```
typedef void (*FunctionCallback)();
```

is a type of pointer to a function with no argument list. So it is compatible, as mafso said it.

```
typedef void (*FunctionCallback)(void);
```

would mean a pointer to a function that expects zero arguments. This would only be compatible with other functions taking zero arguments. ( Note it differs from C++, where `fun()` is the same as `fun(void)` in C )

EDIT:

I would emphasise more, that one still needs to get the arguments right, each time. Meanwhile, the compiler can't help you with that, so, hm, good luck with that.

I can imagine a compiler, that wants to be clever, sees you never ever store the address of any `fun(const char*)` , and use this to optimize your code, thus removing the call to `first`.

Comment: The first paragraph is a little misleading, a `char *` can point to read-only memory (but you cannot write to it and it's your responsibility to check for that), and a `const char *` can point to writable memory. But the point still holds, they _could_ theoretically be passed differently to a function. +1 for an example how easy code using such a setup can become undefined.

Comment: Well, it can point to read-only memory, but it is not a requirement. Perhaps, an ABI uses different ways to pass these arguments, and in all cases the compiler needs to do some extra work to make it seem like working smoothly, if a `func(char*)` is called with a `const char*`. Well, as long as the programmer doesn't hide it from the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid, but makes use of old-style declarations, which have been marked obsolescent in C89. The function pointer used to call a function and the function called must be of compatible type and the types of the parameters passed must match those of the definition. Both is true for the code shown.

Note, that this technique doesn't work for variadic functions or functions with an argument which isn't "self-promoting", for example of type `short` or `float`.

Comment: Relevant standard quote (n1570, C99) Section 6.7.6.3/15: "If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier." (Downvoters please take note.) Also, fwiw, pointers to functions can be round-trip casted, so you could do it with explicit casts to/from `void(*)(void)`

Comment: About old-style functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581586/old-style-c-function-declaration