# Passing in multiple of the same type variables in one fuction

Tags: java, c++

In certain languages we are able to declare multiple same type variables like so:

```
int a,b,c,d;
```

Is it possible though to pass them into functions/methods the same way? E.G in C++

```
template<class ItemType>
void add6(ItemType one,two,three,four,five,six){
  //some very interesting code
}
```

Or would you have to type ItemType in front of every single one? If the Languages I tagged (C++ and Java) can't do this, are there any others that can?

Would there be any cases where this can not be done if it can be done in general?

Also is there a name for this?

Thanks!

++++++++++++++

**Edit**: I have noticed that what I am asking for is unclear and I am going to clarify it

When doing

```
int a,b,c,d;
```

I am declaring all four of those variables at once, mainly because it is faster when typing than doing this:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
```

What I am trying to understand is if that same concept would apply within a functions signature. 
E.G Doing

```
void func(int a,b,c,d){
  //some interesting code
}
```

Instead of

```
void func(int a, int b, int c, int d){
  //some interesting code
}
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: Er, is this Java or is this C++?

Comment: @Dúthomhas The question clearly implies that OP is interested in both, and possibly in other languages with this kind of feature.

Comment: For C++, take a look at [Variadic arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the variable-length argument list syntax (see @HungVo's answer) you can declare an unspecified number of *trailing* arguments of the same type in both Java and C++. 
But for the individually named arguments at the front of the parameter list, however, you must write the type along with each parameter name.

However, some other languages, such as Pascal and Ada, *do* offer a parameter list syntax that allows you to declare multiple consecutive arguments of the same type without having to repeat the type name.  In Pascal, for instance, you could define a procedure `aProc` which takes arguments of the types `INTEGER`, `INTEGER`, `INTEGER`, and `REAL` (in that order) with:

```
PROCEDURE aProc (a, b, c: INTEGER; x: REAL);
BEGIN
  ...
END;
```

The Ada equivalent would be nearly identical:

```
PROCEDURE aProc (a, b, c: INTEGER; x: FLOAT) IS
BEGIN
    ...
END aProc;
```

But in Java (or C++), you'd have to write:

```
void aProc(int a, int b, int c, float x)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The only answer that actually answers the question. There is also old style c syntax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581586/old-style-c-function-declaration (only for c not c++).

Comment: Good golly, @Oleg!  That sure  takes me back to the "good old days"!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to send multiple parameters to method

You can do it in Java using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

Example

```
public static void print( Object... values){
   for(Object c : values){
      System.out.println(c);
   }
}

print("string1","string2",1,2,3,4,5);
```

=================

With [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) in C++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void Output() {
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Output(First arg, const Strings&... rest) {
    std::cout<<arg<<" ";
    Output(rest...);
}

int main() {
    Output("I","am","a","sentence");
    Output("Let's","try",1,"or",2,"digits");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, This was really informative. I reread my question and noticed I was unclear in what I was asking though, and I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
public void varargs(Object ... args)
```

Then u can call it with:

```
varargs(new Object(), new Object());
```

A vararg does not limit the number of objects to be put into the parameter.

Java will automatically store all the passed objects into an array, so you can treat a vararg as an array, eg. You can iterate though each element in the vararg (array).

You can put an array into a vararg, but make sure the type of the array is same as the type of the vararg. If you put an array into an Object vararg and the type of the array is not object, Java may consider the array as a single element and not an array of elements. Consider the following code:

```
public static boolean test(Object ... args) {
    for (Object object : args) {
        if (object.getClass().isArray()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test(new int[] {1, 2})); 
//Prints true
}
```